# Trying to run Ionic 6 project on external phone using cordova

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic6

I'm trying to run a blank project of Ionic 6 on my external phone since it's easier for me to dev on an external since PC lags if I'll use an emulator. [Ionic CLI shows this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nGFC.png) ADB devices also shows my device is detected but there is no application installed in my device. Tried this on two different devices and it's the same.

Comment: if you are not using any native plugin you can simply use `ionic serve --external` and open IP address you get from ionic serve command in your mobile browser to see app. if you are using Native APIS like camera, location etc then you can use `ionic cordova run android --livereload` to see live changes on your device. 
P.S: Check you have developer options enabled on your phone and development permission.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Hi I tried this. And when I open up the server using my phone. CLI says app is deployed but there is no application installed on my phone.

Comment: check application list in settings. if you see your app. please uninstall it from there. and rebuild and check. some time your application gets installed but not shows in UI. check from settings and uninstall it.